# Does {} consume less memory than [] for nested objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, requirejs

I had some legacy JS code that creates a giant nested object structure with []. 
The code goes some like this

```
var data = [];
data ["first"] = [];
data ["first"]["second"] = [];
data ["first"]["second2"] = "hello";
```

It is about 250+ KB of javascript, which is fairly large. When I try to wrap it around with requirejs to load into another requirejs module, it throws Out Of Memory error.

The error goes away if I use {} where I was using [].

I did some homework on [] vs. {} over the weekend and the cause seems to be that using associated arrays as nested dictionaries may be leaky in Javascript since array extends a JS Object and may have more update stuff going on when appending new objects into it. But does it explain the memory consumption issue? Or it is related to how Requirejs parse a module's object?

I don't have enough knowledge about doing JS memory instrumentation and make comparisons between using {} or [] in browser engines, so it is hard to reach conclusions. Any hint or suggestion on how to instrument {} vs. [] would be welcome.

**Update:** I tried some sizeOf() via node yesterday. I used all of the existing ones: "js-sizeof", "object-sizeof", "sizeof"

Code:

```
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof');


var obj = [];
obj['ball'] = 'hello';
obj['air'] = 'hello';
obj['ball']['fire'] = 'world';
obj['ball']['ice'] = [];
console.log(sizeof(obj));

var obj2 = {};
obj2['ball'] = 'hello';
obj2['air'] = 'hello';
obj2['ball']['fire'] = 'world';
obj2['ball']['ice'] = [];
console.log(sizeof(obj2));
```

The results is

[]: 34
{}: 34

The sizeOf is actually the same., but maybe something else happened with [] that could trigger out of memory issue. I am not sure if it is the requirejs parsing it that trigger it or some V8 optimization path. I don't think the Lint tools even suggest against this practice so it is rather ambiguous which way is the "right" way in practice

Comment: they're all objects, but if anything, `{}` will consume more since you have to store the string of the key, instead of just an integer index.

Comment: @MarcB: Wrong.  That would depend on what keys you use, not whether it's an array.

Comment: [Using array for this purpose is just wrong](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). Doesn't matter that they consume more memory as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "associated array" in JavaScript. `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` is array literal syntax; it initializes an Array. `{ foo: "bar" }` is object literal syntax; it initializes an Object. A quirk of JavaScript, however, is that Arrays also happen to be Objects, which is why this code "works":

```
var data = [];
data["first"] = [];
data["first"]["second"] = [];
```

...but you shouldn't do it, because it doesn't make any sense. You're initializing an empty Array (`[]`), but then you're not using it like an Array—you're using it like an Object. If you're using property names (`data["first"]`, which is equivalent to `data.first`) instead of integer keys (`data[0]`), then you want to use an Object. There is no scenario in which you should initialize an Array when you're going to use it like an Object.

As a rule of thumb, if you need each item to have a name, or need to be able to access them quickly by a name, use an Object (`{}`) and use strings for keys. If you need to be able to iterate over the items in order, use an Array with integers for keys.

I don't know the exact cause of your out-of-memory error—especially not without seeing your actual code—but it is definitely the case that you should be using an Object (`{}`), not an Array (`[]`) when you're not using integer keys. JavaScript engines optimize everything they can, and Arrays and Objects are no exception, so it's not surprising that when you use an Array in a way that the engine doesn't expect it might cause performance or memory problems.

P.S. As a matter of style, consider using property notation (or "dot notation," i.e. `foo.bar`) instead of subscript notation (i.e. `foo["bar"]`) when dealing with Objects:

```
var data = {};
data.first = {};
data.first.second = {};
data.first.second2 = "hello";
```

This is exactly equivalent to the code you posted, but it's easier to read and might help you remember that Objects and Arrays have different uses. You could also just express this as a single object literal:

```
var data = {
  first: {
    second: {},
    second2: "hello"
  }
};
```

This is also exactly equivalent and helps you see the "structure" of your object (as long as you're disciplined about indentation).

Most JavaScript style guides say that you should always use "dot notation" unless you have keys that would cause a syntax error. For example, if you have a property named `"foo/bar"`, you obviously can't do this:

```
var obj.foo/bar = 1;
```

...because it's a syntax error. So you have to do this:

```
var obj["foo/bar"] = 1;
```

...which is perfectly valid. These cases tend to be the exception, so I would encourage to always use dot notation unless you *have to* use subscript notation.

Comment: My understanding is that ary = [1,2,3] initialises an object {1: 1, 2: 2, 3:3} which is why ary[10000000] = 123 works without crashing your machine. All arrays are objects, and all objects work like associated arrays (lists (LISP)) but they have a few extra methods which let you initialise them sensibly, get the length, etc. The example above would be better written in JSON, but I currently disagree with your reasons why. Can you convince me otherwise?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in my first paragraph. And I have no incentive to convince you, so I'm afraid you'll have to remain unsatisfied with my answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, I just believed myself mistaken.

Comment: Ah, well, my apologies for being brusque.

Comment: I wonder if the out of memory had to do with how Requirejs works at all. I was also using it inside a Karma test, which adds another layer of abstraction. Though I agree that we probably should move away from using array as objects. I just needed to be certain before we change 500+ of these types of scripts everywhere